# json data not rendered in backbone view

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have been trying to render the json data to the view by calling 
the rest api and the code is as follows:

```
var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend({       
    dataType:'jsonp',
    defaults: {
        intuitId: null,
        email: null,
        type: null      
    },  
});     
var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({      
    model: Profile,         
    url: '/v1/entities/6414256167329108895'
});     
var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    el: "#profiles",
    template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),         
    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile) {
            var profileTemplate = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            $(this.el).append(tprofileTemplate);
        }, this);
        return this;        
    }
});     
var profiles = new ProfileList();   
var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});  
profiles.fetch();
profilesView.render();
```

and the html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>SPA Example</title> 
        <!-- 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/reset.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/harmony_compiled.css" /> 
        --> 
    </head>
    <body class="harmony">
        <header>        
            <div class="title">SPA Example</div>    
        </header>
        <div id="profiles"></div>   
        <script id="profileTemplate" type="text/template"> 
            <div class="profile"> 
                <div class="info"> 
                    <div class="intuitId"> 
                        <%= intuitId %> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="email"> 
                        <%= email %> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="type"> 
                        <%= type %> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This gives me an error and the `render` function isn't invoking 
properly and the `render` function is called even before the REST
API returns the JSON response.

Could anyone please help me to figure out where I went wrong. Any help is highly appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to pass the model attributes to the template function explicitly. So change the appropriate code in the view to:

```
var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    el: "#profiles",
    //template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()), REMOVED         
    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile) {
            var profileTemplate = _.template($('#profileTemplate').html(), {
                  intuitId: profile.get("intuitId"),
                  email: profile.get("email"),
                  type: profile.get("type")
                });
            $(this.el).append(tprofileTemplate);
        }, this);
        return this;        
    }
});
```

Secondly, your render method is not dependent on the fetch response from being returned from the server. It will get called immediately after the line above it executes and not wait for the fetch response. This behavior you are experiencing is by design. If you want to call render after you get the response back from the server you'll have to use events. You could replace `profilesView.render();` with something like:

```
profilesView.listenTo(profiles, "sync", profilesView.render);
```

This means that the `profilesView` will listen for the `profiles` collection to complete its fetch and fire a `sync` event. When this occurs, the `render` function of the view will be called.